# Why the order of references changes when cite is used?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I have spent my night to narrow down the problem but couldn't fix it.

This is my `main.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{url}

%\usepackage{cite}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor IEEE-Xplore}
% updated with editoria

\begin{document}


\section{Result}
\label{section:Result}
One example is from ~\cite{FosterEtAl:2003}.

\section*{Acknowledgments}
This should be a simple paragraph before the References to thank those individuals and institutions who have supported your work on this article.
%
\newpage
%

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,references.bib}

\vspace{11pt}
\end{document}
```

and this is the `references.bib` which locates on the same folder.

```
@article{knuth:1984,
  title={Literate Programming},
  author={Donald E. Knuth},
  journal={The Computer Journal},
  volume={27},
  number={2},
  pages={97--111},
  year={2020},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}
@inproceedings{FosterEtAl:2003,
  author = {George Foster and Simona Gandrabur and Philippe Langlais and Pierre
    Plamondon and Graham Russell and Michel Simard},
  title = {Statistical Machine Translation: Rapid Development with Limited Resources},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of {MT Summit IX}},
  year = {2016},
  pages = {110--119},
  address = {New Orleans, USA},
}
@phdthesis{Alsolami:2012,
    title    = {An examination of keystroke dynamics
                for continuous user authentication},
    school   = {Queensland University of Technology},
    author   = {Eesa Alsolami},
    year     = {2012}
}
```

I want the order of references should be same as in the `references.bib`. However, I noticed a strange thing that the order is right if I remove `~\cite{FosterEtAl:2003}` and it messed up if the cite is used.

Why does this happen?
How can I fix it?

Comment: what matters is the order you cite. Move the \nocite{*} at the begin of the document.

Comment: although `\nocite` will do what you want, it is best to think of a `.bib` file as an un-ordered database of _possible_ references. Many people collect very large bib files of every document in the area and use the same one in all documents. bibtex extracts just the references `\cite` in a document and constructs a bibliography.

Comment: But the problem is that you're not always cite references in increasing order.

Comment: Think from the reader's point of view. He will like to locate a particular cited work in a list of many references as soon as possible. Either they are numbered or they are in alphabetical order or use some code The order in which you cited or how many times you did it does not matter. Most of the time I start reading the conclusions.

Comment: @emnha I do not understand your comment the numbers are assigned by bibtex depending on the \cite. You may have 10,000 entries in the .bib, in any order,  but if your document has ...`\cite{David}` ...`\cite{Ulrike}` ... then bibtex will make a 2-reference bibliography with David being `[1]` and Ulrike being `[2]` so `\cite` _determine_ the order.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sometimes you have the situation like [1]-[5] and then you also have [3], [6]. So how is the order determined here?

Comment: @hana sorry I do not understand. You just \cite with symbolic key names, numbers are assigned either in citation order or alphabetic order of authors, according to the bibliography style and a suitable citation text is generated. If you really need to force an order you can use `\nocite{Ulrike} \cite{David} ... \cite{Ulrike}` so in the printed output it will be `[2]  ... [1]` with Ulrike getting `[1]` because of the earlier `\nocite`.

Comment: @emnha that is for 1-5 you go `\cite{aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee}` and cite all the entries latex can compress the list to 1-5 or show 1,2,3,4,5 depending on options set

Comment: @DavidCarlisle assume that at the begining you cite `\cite{aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee}` then `aaa -> [1],  bbb-> [2], ccc->[3], ddd->[4], eee->[5]`. However, later in the paper you also refer to `cite{ccc}` again so would it assign `ccc->[6]` now?

Comment: @emnha no of course not, each entry only appears in the bibliography once and is ordered according to first use. Just try it, people have been using bibtex for 30 years, it does work...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle actually I did that first and it didn't work. But now  I realized that I did multiple citations wrong. I should have writen `\cite{aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee}` instead of `\cite{aaa}--\cite{eee}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IEEEtran` style uses *unsorted* citations, so the first cited item ends up first in the references section, followed by the second cited and so on.

In your example, “Foster” is the first cited item, so you get it first in the references. That's all.

If you really want to use the same order as in the `.bib` file (but I wonder why you would), then put `\nocite{*}` just after `\begin{document}`, because this effectively “cites” everything in the `.bib` file.